# Unable to infer type of array's elements when using array in initialization

Tags: typescript

This is a wild simplification of my code, but when initializing an array using a while-loop, and using that array in the initialization:

```
const chunks = [];

while (Math.random() > 0.5) {
  const header = chunks.length; // ! error

  chunks.push(header);
}
```

TypeScript will get mad and tell me,

> 'header' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.

which I do understand and sympathize with. After all, I am clearly going to push `header` to `chunks`, and since `chunks` is needed to initialize `header`, it is indeed referenced indirectly in its own initializer. However, `chunks.length` is obviously a number. Array lengths should always be numbers.

Why then, is TypeScript not using the `number` type for `header`? It's instead marking it as an implicit `any`, and it's *ignoring* the correct type...

I mean, sure, I could make the error go away with an annotation:

```
const header: number = chunks.length;
```

but that's redundant, annoying, and hard to digest. Someone else reading this code might question this redundant annotation and remove it, only to see the error above appear again.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/N72ZDw)

Comment: What if you explicitly give `chunks` a type, e.g. `const chunks: any[] = [];` or `const chunks: unknown[] = []`? This seems to stem from a bug in TypeScript: see the ticket here: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43047

Comment: that has to be a bug, this does not happend when outside the `while` loop.

Comment: You can inline `header` or hoist its declaration above the loop [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBMAWBXMBrCBGGBeGBtAugNwBQxANgKazwUCGAJhQE4nEDu8AlpTABQCytKPAB0TWmHogAtrwCUMAHwwADCICsCgN7EYMGg2bY4SVBhGUwAc2Ek9CZGnQiADogjxeBxkzkkAvqSgkLAOZgBMxgSsHNwUfILCYhJSsgrKapowOvamaOGu7p5h+RYU1sJ+xP5AA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems seems to be a bug/shortcomming of TS that has already be reported multiple times but the closest instance I found was: [#36687](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36687).
*